# Hide order status from frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, backend, frontend, order-status

I have created some order statuses.
One order status is a backend status.

Is it possible to hide this status from the frontend?

As example say you have status A and status B.

First you assign status A and a few days later you assign status B witch is only for backend users visible.

Customers who are logged in should see status A as active status instead of status B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not "hiding" an order status, you want to show a previous status rather than a current status under certain circumstances. Effectively you want to have a current public status and a current backend status. That's a significant change.

Rather than introducing two separate statuses into a system that is built around having just one, you could more easily solve this issue by having separate language on frontend and backend.

The frontend text for statuses A and B would be the same.
The backend text for statuses A and B would be different.

This assumes that there is a definite link between the two statuses, and that the public always appear to still see status A if it's status B.

For example, if status A is "Preparing pizza", and status B is "Removing all signs of having dropped pizza on floor", this would be fine. But if you sometimes wanted to use status B while displaying status C "Pizza is on the bike", you'd have to split that status too.

As a result, it will definitely be advisable to keep the public status within the backend language, so status B would read  "Preparing pizza [Removing all signs of having dropped pizza on floor]".

Another way to approach this would be to find a way of communicating Status B that is appropriate to the customer - eg customer sees "Quality Control", backend sees "Checking for mouse droppings".

If you are fiddling with language, be careful that emails don't send the backend language by mistake.

The non-programming solution is to just have one status frontend and back that is a euphemism for the desired status but appears innocuous to the customer.

Comment: Thanks I have added a differtent frontend label to the order status. And that works good enough :)